# Sharing a string across many classes JAVA

Tags: java

I would like to share a string across a couple of classes in java, however the string is not constant, so the usual method of `public static final` does not work.

I mean, I update the value of string, and this varies from use.

Currently the code I am using is:

```
public String NewDestination;

 destination = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/Uploaded/"; // main location for uploads (CHANGE THIS WHEN USING PREDATOR)
            File theFile = new File(destination + "/" + username);
            theFile.mkdirs();// will create a sub folder for each user (currently does not work, below hopefully is a solution) (DOES NOW WORK)
            System.out.println("Completed Creation of folder");
            NewDestination = destination + username + "/";
```

Above, it is created from adding together destination + username + "/", so it can not be static final as this changes on each log in, but I still need the value passed to another class, how can I do this ?

EDIT:

What I have now done is:

added `public static String NewDestination;` to my FileUploadController.java

and in my Mybean.java I added `System.out.println(FileUploadController.NewDestination);` and it still out prints null :(

Comment: Why not "public static String NewDestination;" ?

Comment: `public static` might be what you are looking for. If multiple threads are accessing this value, make it `public static volatile` and make sure to get the synchronization right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `public static` non-`final` field.

However, this would allow other classes to change it too.
It would be better to make a `private static` field, and a `public static getDestination()` method to allow other classes to read it.

Comment: Thank you, i have made it a private static field, the NewDestination is located in FileUploadController.java i want to use it in MyBean.java, how do i call it in MyBean to use ?, sorry if these are really simple question im new to java

Comment: `System.out.println(FileUploadController.getNewDestination);` i have tried, but it does not find the getNewDestination

Comment: @user2039362: You need to _call_ the function, using `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you *can't* change a `String`. Strings are immutable. You're passing around a *reference* to a `String`, and it's the *reference* that will change, not the underlying `String`.

If each class requires a reference to a changing `String`, why not simply generate the `String` in a method as required and have each class call:

```
originatingObject.getDestinationPath();
```

That's easier to handle in a threaded environment (certainly more so than using a `static` instance which makes some assumptions re. usage)

Answer (score 0):

String data type in Java is immutable. In your case since the value stored in variable "destination" changes, I would recommend using StringBuilder (this is mutable companion class of String).